# How will completed TComponent's WriteState

Tags: delphi, components, dfm

I know by reading the stream, using the TComponent.Loaded method, that all other components are ready.
Similar to Loaded, exists something by writing, that say, all components are written?

thanks

Comment: I suppose you could override `WriteState` and hope that all the things you want to hook go through there. But I can't imagine why you would ever want to hook the end of state writing.

Comment: I have a descendant component with many levels of subproperties. I wan't implement the property-classes on sub-sub-sub levels, but I have other default values, and these wan't write back in the DFM. On WriteState of my component I can set the orig. defaults (before inherited), so avoiding the writing. But if I set back my values after **inherited** in my WriteState, I receive the error message _can't write to read-only resource stream_ . So I need set the values after all components from dfm are written.

Comment: I'm fairly sure your proposed solution is the wrong way to solve this. Don't you just use IsStored to disable streaming? This appears to be an XY problem. If you would explain the problem rather than asking how to implement your solution, you'd likely do better.

Comment: I can't use _stored_, because my component does not have this property directly, it's in a sub-sub property from the father-class

Comment: Well, I still have no idea what your real problem is. Sorry, but I can't help.